# IF and ELSE both are eventuating at same time in dos

Tags: batch

I am not able to figure out why at the same time, both IF and ELSE are satisfying the condition.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

    Set filename=Credit_Limits\Input\BR_Credit_Limit_Upload.csv
    if exist %filename% (
        FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%A IN (%filename%) DO ( 
                  if %%~A == External_ID_vod__c (
                    if %%~B == M_NA_BR_Credit_Limit_CU__c (
                        if %%~C == CurrencyISOCode (
                            echo good
                        )
                    )
                  )   
                  goto :break
                )
        )
        :break      
    ) else (
        echo file doesn't exist
    )
```

I am getting below output always:

```
good 
file doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First*: there is one extra `)` closing parenthesis in your code; simplified example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
if 1==1 (
  echo good
  )
) else (
  echo file doesn't exist
)
```

Output:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\993931.bat
good
file doesn't exist
```

*Second*: as a general rule, **never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses. For proof and examples, read

- [Using `GOTO` within parenthesis - including `FOR` and `IF` commands - will break their context](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [This my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404)

*Finally*, as

- `%%~A` or `%%~B` or `%%~C` could contain some `cmd` [poisonous characters that should be escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), or
- `%%~B` or `%%~C` could result to empty string (try `if  == A echo any`),

use (again as a general rule) proper double quoting as follows:

```
              if "%%~A" == "External_ID_vod__c" (
                if "%%~B" == "M_NA_BR_Credit_Limit_CU__c" (
                    if "%%~C" == "CurrencyISOCode" (
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FOR loop is still running after the condition is met. It hits the condition, outputs "good", keeps running the loop the next cycles, to which hit the condition again resulting in a false and giving you the "file doesn't exist" output.

You should either add a condition to your FOR loop that will make the code exit it in the result that the true condition is reached, or put a goto, to bypass the false condition if true is met.

Comment: My understanding is if `if exist %filename%` condition is not met then only control will go to else part and will print "file doesn't exist"?

Comment: You can just put your "goto :break" after your "echo good" and put your ":break" after your IF statement on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to just not use an ELSE statement.  The following example uses fewer parenthesis than the earlier sample code, yet should be equivalent.

```
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set filename=Credit_Limits\Input\BR_Credit_Limit_Upload.csv
if NOT exist %filename% goto nofile

FOR /F "tokens=1-3* delims=," %%A IN (%filename%) DO (
    if "%%~A" == "External_ID_vod__c" if "%%~C" == "CurrencyISOCode" (
        if "%%~B" == "M_NA_BR_Credit_Limit_CU__c" echo good
    )
)    
goto done

:nofile
echo File doesn't exist

:done
```